Combining and manipulating column values in several rows based on the values of a separate column
TL;DR: How to group rows by an ID column, preserve the values of a large number of the columns and sum a small number of them?
I have a relatively large dataframe which is from a clinical study (1000 columns x 1000 rows).
To make it easier to explain, let's say for simplicity this data is for users of gym. It is quite annoyingly formatted.
Every user has one master row where they have a lot of information recorded about them (900+ columns). For each visit to the gym, each user has an extra visit row containing the time they spent in each area.
Master rows have NAs in the visit time columns, and visit rows have NAs in the master columns. There are also some data missing.
An example is below:

              #master row information#        #visit row information
gym_id  name    weight  height (900+ col data)  time_gym  time_sauna  time_cafe      
001     Alice   130     60         ...          NA        NA          NA             
001     Alice   NA      NA         ...          20        NA          10 
001     Alice   NA      NA         ...          60        NA          NA 
002     Bob     200     70         ...          NA        NA          NA                          
003     Eve     140     70         ...          NA        NA          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...         100        10          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          80        NA          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          50        15          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          50        10          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          60        NA           5
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          40        NA          NA
003     Eve     NA      NA         ...          80         5          NA

....

Code to create this is:
gym_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
name <- c('Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', "Eve", "Eve", "Eve", "Eve", "Eve", "Eve", "Eve", "Eve")
weight <- c(130, NA, NA, 200, 140, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
height <- c(60, NA, NA, 70, 70, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
time_gym <- c(NA, 20, 60, NA, NA, 100, 80, 50, 50, 60, 40, 80)
time_sauna <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, 15, 10, NA, NA, 5)
time_cafe <- c(NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA)

gym <- data.frame(gym_id, name, weight, height, time_gym, time_sauna, time_cafe)

I want to combine the rows so that there is one row per user, with their master information and their total visit time for each area. I ideally want to use dplyr as I find it easier to understand. The example above would become:

              #master row information#        #visit row information
gym_id  name    weight  height (900+ col data)  total_gym  total_sauna   total_cafe      
001     Alice   130     60         ...           80         0            10
002     Bob     200     70         ...            0         0             0
003     Eve     140     70         ...          460        40             5         

Adding the extra columns for total time and dealing with the NAs is fine.
I have tried using mutate(), group_by(), summarise() in various combinations but I am struggling to find the solution as I always lose the rest of the other columns, e.g. by using the following:
gym %>%
  group_by(gym_id) %>%
  summarise(total_gym = sum(time_gym), total_sauna = sum(time_sauna))

The only way I can find to preserve the columns seems to be to specify each column in the summarise() code and can't specify all 900+ columns in the code. Alternatively, I have ended up creating two different dataframes as a workaround - one master and one total times frame but this causes further problems with analysis dowstream.
I am sure there is a really easy way to do this and I know how I would do it in other languages but am struggling to find it in R.
Thank you in advance!

in Base R, you could use aggregate:
 aggregate(.~gym_id+name, gym, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = identity)

  gym_id  name weight height time_gym time_sauna time_cafe
1      1 Alice    130     60       80          0        10
2      2   Bob    200     70        0          0         0
3      3   Eve    140     70      460         40         5


You could use across()
summarize(gym, across(weight:time_cafe, ~sum(.x,na.rm = T)),.by = c(gym_id, name))

Output:
  gym_id  name weight height time_gym time_sauna time_cafe
1      1 Alice    130     60       80          0        10
2      2   Bob    200     70        0          0         0
3      3   Eve    140     70      460         40         5

